# How can I use the WiFi device connected through bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I figure out if I have WiFi devices connected to my PC thru bash scripting?

- Is there anyway aside from 'iwconfig'?
- Suppose I have two devices connected and am using device A. Now if device A
  is down, how can I setup to use device B instead?

Answer (score -2):

```
depend() {
        before fuse
}

start() {
        ebegin "Starting Networking"
        /etc/init.d/net.eth0 start

       if [ `ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 | grep "Destination Host Unreachable"` ]; then
                /etc/init.d/net.eth0 stop

                if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/net.wlan0 start
                fi
        fi
        eend
}
```

Change according to ur Wlan card name .

this information taken from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/detect-if-a-network-device-is-connected-in-a-bash-script-692824/

Comment: As far as I am aware, only Gentoo uses `openrc` for network setup.  Debian uses `ifupdown` and Fedora uses `sysconfig`; this solution will work on neither.